# Building a function expression that accepts a character and returns true when the character is either , . ! ; and returns false otherwise

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty constructing a function expression that accepts a single character.  When the character is either , . ; ! the statement will result true.  When the character is none of the 4 listed, it should return false.

I have tried many different variations of the code listed below.  The problem is, the function returns true whenever any assortment of characters are inside of a string. For example, when I run isPunct("a") the functions returns true.  When in reality, it should only return true when , . ! or ; is entered.

```
let isPunct = function(ch) {
    let punctList = /,.;!/;
    if (ch != punctList) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
};
```

I expect it to return true when ; . , or ! is entered
However, I can input anything in a string, and it returns true.

`isPunct("example")` returns true.

Also, I apologize if this question is poorly worded I have only been learning Javascript for 3 weeks.

Comment: The question boils down to why `"example" != /,.;!/` is true. Or any other string instead of `"example"`.

Comment: @hlg `'asdas' != /,.;!/ ` returns true because they are not equal. `typeof(/,.;!/)` is an 'object ' while the other is string. Makes sense?

Comment: Sure, to me this is obvious. Just suggesting to simplify the question.

Answer (score 2):

To construct a regular expression that matches one of any of a set of characters, use the syntax for a character set, eg

```
[abc]
```

to match `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Also, to match a regular expression against a string, use `.test` or `.match`:

```js
const isPunct = char => /[,.!;]/.test(char);

console.log(
  isPunct('.'),
  isPunct('a')
);
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (click the checkbox) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your if condition. With `punctList` you tried to create a regex expression.

In order to match it against your string, you need to use `.match` or `.test`. It returns `True` if your string matches with regex and `False` otherwise

```
if (ch.match(punctList))
```

---

So the function can be just changed to below as technically you don't need an If condition

```
let isPunct = function(ch) {
    let punctList = /,.;!/;
    return ch.match(punctList);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @scoducks2021 if it helped, can you please mark it as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
let isPunct = function(ch) {

     return "/,.;!/".indexOf(ch) > -1;
  };
```